# How to pass list data to other method

Tags: c#

I have method which return `list` and I want to pass that list from `GetAndPost` method to `Test` method.. I have no idea how to do that!

Code:

```
    public List<string> GetAndPost()
    {
        Connection();
        con.Open();

        com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Statement ", con);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            TXNID = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            docType = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            docNo = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
            ctryIssue = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
            name = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
            expDate = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
            citizen = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
            dob = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();

            gender = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
            mbikeNo = reader.GetValue(9).ToString();
            mbikeExpDate = reader.GetValue(10).ToString();
            branch = reader.GetValue(14).ToString();
            status = reader.GetValue(12).ToString();
            if (status == "False")
            {


            }

        }
        reader.Close();

        Console.WriteLine(list);
        return list;

    }

    public List<string> Test()
    {

    }
```

Comment: Your list is always empty, you just declare it and not adding anything in it. Hope it is for the sake of explanation...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it like this

```
Test(list);
```

And this is how test method should look like

```
public void Test(List<string> list)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<string> Test(List<string> stringList)
{

}
```

Then just call your Test method by passing your list to it, like;

```
Test(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I will declare a variable that will hold the output of `GetAndPost` function.

```
var getAndPostList = GetAndPost();

...
// Pass value to another function
Test(getAndPostList);
```

And for your `Test` function, it should expect a list of strings

```
public List<string> Test(List<string> getAndPostList)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass  as a List

```
public void somefunction(List<YourType> dates)
{
}
```

However, it's better to use the most generic (as in general, base) interface possible, so I would use

```
public void somefunction(IEnumerable<YourType> dates)
{
}
```

or

```
public void somefunction(ICollection<YourType> dates)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Test()` function should be like so (in case that `Test()` doesn't has to return a value):

```
public void Test(List<string> stringList)
{

}
```

On your `GetAndPost()` function:

```
return list;
```

Then call your `Test()` function:

```
test(GetAndPost());
```

If you want to call the `Test()` function withinn your `GetAndPost()` function replace your `return` with:

```
test(list);
```

And change the declaration of `GetAndPost()` to:

```
public void GetAndPost()
{
//YOUR CODE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Test` method should expect a list argument if you want to pass this list.

```
public List<string> Test(List<string> list)
```

and then call this method from anywhere in your `GetAndPost` method.

```
Test(list);
```

You don't have to return a list from the `Test` method even if you are expecting to change the contents of the list. `List` is a class type and passed as reference. You can edit the same list in `Test` method and access the modifications from `GetAndPost` method.